# Rjava package installation freeze in a docker

Tags: java, r, docker

Inside a docker when i try to install a the rJava package it freezes.
in the "checking whether -Xrs is supported." process
It works outside a docker ...
And for the JNI and opnjdk i've purge it and put link to link the sun jdk instead of openjdk 
Here are the log :

```
> install.packages("rJava", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
essai de l'URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 656615 bytes (641 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 641 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rJava’ ...
** package ‘rJava’ correctement décompressé et sommes MD5 vérifiées
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
configure: checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 supports static inline...
yes
checking whether setjmp.h is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking whether sigsetjmp is declared... yes
checking whether siglongjmp is declared... yes
checking Java support in R... present:
interpreter : '/usr/bin/java'
archiver    : '/usr/bin/jar'
compiler    : '/usr/bin/javac'
header prep.: '/usr/bin/javah'
cpp flags   : '-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.45.x86_64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.45.x86_64/include/linux'
java libs   : '-L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm'
checking whether Java run-time works... yes
checking whether -Xrs is supported...
```

if anyone have any idea
thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a docker issue : https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/63